# How to get information about width and height of View inside of .background() modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to create a button like this:

[image: SwiftUI Button with stroke]

Here is the code for that:

```
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryTextColor"))
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .strokeBorder(Color("MainBackgroundColor"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, dash: [8]))
                            .frame(width: 345, height: 70)
                    )
                    .background(Color("SecondaryBackgroundColor"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                }
```

Right now you can see that background RounderRectangle has fixed width and height. I would like to calculate the values for the stroke to be dynamic and always a little bit less than the Vstack. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need padding (it gives constant internal inset independently of external size, ie. internal stroke will always fit in filled area):

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.1)
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        .strokeBorder(Color("MainBackgroundColor"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, dash: [8]))
        .padding(4)  // << here !! (set value per needs)
)
```

[image]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5